# Create XSD that matches any element with no attributes and no children

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, .net-4.6

I have a requirement to create a XSD file to safely process XML that we are getting. The XML will be like this:

```
<Books>
  <Book>
    <abc>hello</abc>
    <xyz>crazy</xyz>
    <q123>world</q123>
    ...
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <abc>bye</abc>
    <xyz>bye</xyz>
    <q123></q123>
    ...
  </Book>
</Books>
```

- The `<Books>` element is the root element so there will only be one.
- The `<Book>` element occur between 1 to 100.

The trouble is with the subelements of the `<Book>` element.

- The occurance of must be between 1 to 500.
- The subelements can be **any** name.
- The name must be 1 to 100 characters in length.
- They can be in any order.
- The subelement cannot have any attributes.
- The subelement value can be 0 to 100 characters in length.

The good news is each `<Book>` element will have the same number and the same order of subelements. Below is the XSD I have so far. This based off of the answer from [XSD for varying element names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024492/xsd-for-varying-element-names?rq=1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="Books">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Book" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1000">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:any processContents="strict" namespace="##local" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="500"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="every $e in * satisfies matches(local-name($e), '.{1,100}')"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

When I try to parse the XML I'm getting this error: `The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:assert' element is not supported in this context.`

I'm not sure why I am getting that error. Also I have no idea how to test the value of the subelement is between 0 and 100 characters, and how to make sure it has 0 attributes.

I'm working in C# .NET 4.6. Thanks in advance!

Comment: With sub-elements be any name this would be better implemented using a Dictionary.

Comment: @jdweng We have no control over the XML given to us unfortunately. :(

Comment: .NET has no native support XSD 1.1.

Comment: I just meant parse value into a dictionary.

Comment: How do I keep track of Books without using attributes! You can create a while loop plus Element validation to check how many books you have so far for every XML book instance 
you are processing, then stop at 500 mark. For example.

On C# code, you will have to validate the Books, Book element first with an if statement before processing i.e 
int count =0;
if (Books.Book != null && count <= 100)
{
count++; 
...
... keep processing
}
else
return;

Comment: Subelements Part.
You will have to code each line or everything that follows after the Book element. So you can write a code that check 
if you have reached </Book> or end, if not expect a line that starts with "<whatever...>" ... and ends with "</whatever>
check the next line, then the following until you encounter </Book> the end of Book 1.

For more Validation info please refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xmlschemavalidator-push-based-validation

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: You'll have some source about non-support in .net?